# efficient way to match users common data in the database?

Tags: mysql, sql

An example:  The user can enter his hobbies, like 'golf, football, tennis'.
I want to list all the users with the same hobbies (or just one of them).

My approach:
A field in the database named 'hobbies' and fill it with all hobbies, seperated with commas like above. Then I get this data with php, fill an array and match the users in a loop.   But it seems this is very unefficent way.

I thought about to save the hobbies in seperate columns in the database, but then I have to set a max limit and still unsure how to match with 50 different columns.

Can someone give me a little advice to the right direction?

Comment: use normaliztion for hobbies otherwise you cannot match them correctly

Comment: Storing multiple values in a comma-delimited field is not the SQL way of representing data.  Use table with separate rows for each user and hobby combination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would do this :

1) `hobbies` Table :

```
+----------+------------+
| id_hobby | hobby_name |
+----------+------------+
|        1 | Football   |
|        2 | Tennis     |
|        3 | Tennis     |
|        4 | T.V.       |
|        5 | Cars       |
|        6 | Swimming   |
|        7 | Coding     |
+----------+------------+
```

2) `users` Table :

```
+---------+-----------+
| id_user | user_name |
+---------+-----------+
|       1 | Bob       |
|       2 | John      |
|       3 | Arnold    |
|       4 | Mary      |
|       5 | Julia     |
|       6 | Amelia    |
+---------+-----------+
```

3) `users_hobbies` Table :

```
+---------+----------+
| id_user | id_hobby |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |        2 |
|       1 |        4 |
|       1 |        6 |
|       2 |        7 |
|       3 |        3 |
|       3 |        4 |
|       3 |        1 |
|       3 |        7 |
|       4 |        5 |
|       5 |        6 |
|       5 |        7 |
|       5 |        2 |
|       6 |        3 |
|       6 |        5 |
|       6 |        7 |
+---------+----------+
```

And then Go through this with php :

```
// init DB connection
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', $db_user, $db_passwd);

// build data arrays
try {
    foreach ($db->query('
        SELECT h.hobby_name, u.user_name FROM hobbies as h
        LEFT JOIN users as u
            INNER JOIN users_hobbies as uh
            ON u.id_user = uh.id_user
        ON h.id_hobby = uh.id_hobby
    ') as $row) {
        $users_hobbies[] = $row;
        $hobbies[] = $row['hobby_name'];
    }
} catch (PDOExeption $e) {
    print "Error! : " . $e->getMessage() . "<br />";
    die();
}

// drop duplicates from $hobbies array
$hobbies = array_unique($hobbies);

// loop through new hobbies array and get users
foreach ($hobbies as $hobby) {
    echo "<h2>" . $hobby . "</h2>";
    foreach ($users_hobbies as $row) {
        if ($row['hobby_name'] == $hobby) {
            echo "<p>" . $row['user_name'] . "</p>";
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

> ### Football
>
> Arnold
>
> ### Tennis
>
> Bob
>
> Julia
>
> Arnold
>
> Amelia
>
> ### T.V.
>
> Bob
>
> Arnold
>
> ### Cars
>
> Mary
>
> Amelia
>
> ### Swimming
>
> Bob
>
> Julia
>
> ### Coding
>
> John
>
> Arnold
>
> Julia
>
> Amelia

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This gives me the right hint, now I know what to do next.

Comment: Keep in mind this is a naive implementation of what you need. You'd better read threads that your question is duplicated.